# Merge 2 collections on a condition to populate a nested collection

Tags: blueprism

I have 2 collections in which I get data from DB.

Collection 1 column names: A_id, Bid, PCid, Bname ==> all text fields

Collection 2 column names: A_ref, Cid, Cname, value ==> all text fields

Collection 1 and 2 are related based on collection1.A_id=collection2.A_ref

I have a 3rd collection which is a nested collection:

Collection 3 Column names: action(text), colA (collection)

colA column names: Bid(text), PCid(text), Bname(text), colB (collection)

colB column names: Cid, Cname, value ==> all text fields

I want to join collection 1 and collection 2 based on mentioned condition to load the nested collection 3.

Please help.

I have tried using the collection VBO but didnt succeed. I also tried using a nested loop stage and counters with a decision stage but my code fails to add empty row to the nested collection before populating the values.

Using Blueprism stages

I want to join collection 1 and collection 2 based on mentioned condition to load the nested collection 3.

I am using a nested loop stage and counters with a decision stage but my code fails to add row to the nested collection.

Comment: Let me clarify, so you want if cells collection1.A_id=collection2.A_ref then to merge these 2 collections and then write the merged collection in collection 3? If yes you want a new sub collection under collection 3?

Comment: Or just to write on the same fields of collection3 the information from fields of Collection 1 and 2, for example Collection 1.Bid to Collection 3.colA.Bid?

Comment: Populate collection 3 which is a nested collection from data from collection 1 and 2. The join of 1 and 2 will be on condition c1.a_id=c2.a_ref

Comment: If Collection 3 has already predefined Fields, then add an empty row in Initial Values tab. You have not specified which of the two approaches i asked above you want to follow.

Answer (score 1):

Aswin, please check the solution below:

[image]

For further information, i will pass the XML file as for you to import to Blue Prism and check every stage, since it would require a lot of time and screenshots to explain everything. Plus you will have a clear understanding of every step in your environment.

Download XML file from my github repository link:

[Blue Prism Merge Collections to populate a nested-collection](https://github.com/KonstantinosPalaiodimos/KonstantinosPalaiodimos)

Hope these information will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is what I call a "box join". You'll need a code stage.

Inputs:

- Main (collection)
- Nested (collection)
- Main Key (text)
- Nested Key (text)
- New Field Name (text)

Outputs:

- Output Collection

Code:

```
' Check for requirements: key columns exist, and that the new field to create in the main
' collection does not already exist.
If Not Main.Columns.Contains(Main_Key) Then
    Throw New Exception("Main Collection does not contain the key column '" & Main_Key & "'")
Else If Not Nested.Columns.Contains(Nested_Key) Then
    Throw New Exception("Nested Collection does not contain the key column '" & Nested_Key & "'")
Else If Main.Columns.Contains(New_Field_Name) Then
    Throw New Exception("Main Collection already contains a field named '" & New_Field_Name & "'")
End If

' Add the column containing the DataTable which will be populated with data from the Nested collection.
Main.Columns.Add(New_Field_Name, GetType(DataTable))

For Each MainRow As DataRow In Main.Rows
    ' Create the new nested table for this row and populate the column names.
    Dim Table As New DataTable
    For Each NestedColumn As DataColumn In Nested.Columns
        Table.Columns.Add(NestedColumn.ColumnName, NestedColumn.DataType)
    Next

    ' Because we don't want to copy the key column.
    Table.Columns.Remove(Nested_Key)

    ' Check each row in the Nested collection to see if it matches current key.
    For Each NestedRow As DataRow In Nested.Rows
        If MainRow(Main_Key) = NestedRow(Nested_Key) Then
            ' Got a match; add the row from Nested into the new table.
            Dim NewRow As DataRow = Table.NewRow
            For Each TableColumn As DataColumn In Table.Columns
                NewRow(TableColumn.ColumnName) = NestedRow(TableColumn.ColumnName)
            Next
            Table.Rows.Add(NewRow)
        End If
    Next

    ' Set the nested collection
    MainRow(New_Field_Name) = Table
Next

Output_Collection = Main
```

Using the example from the question, you'll want to pass the following into the code stage inputs:

- [Collection 1] -> Main
- [Collection 2] -> Nested
- "A_id" -> Main Key
- "A_ref" -> Nested Key
- "colB" -> New Field Name

The resulting Output Collection will contain the fields from Collection 1, with an added column "colB" which contains the fields (excluding the key) from Collection 2. From there, a calculate stage can get the results into Collection 3.

Comment: Thanks Nick for the detailed code. But this does not serve the purpose. If you notice, the output collection expected is a multi nested collection. for example:

Comment: Thanks Nick for the detailed code. But this does not serve the purpose. If you notice, the output collection expected is a multi nested collection. for example:

Collection 1:

{A_id, Bid, PCid, Bname}

{{1, 90001, 40001, Aswin}, {2, 90002, 40002, Navin}}


Collection 2:

{A_ref, Cid, Cname, value}

{{2, 10001, Agarwal, 32},{2, 10002, Kumar, 26}}

Output Collection (Collection 3):

{action,{Bid, PCid, Bname, {Cid, Cname, value}}}

{{"Not Required",{90001, 40001, Aswin}},{"Not Required", {90002, 40002, Navin, {{10001, Agarwal, 32},{10002, Kumar, 26}}}}}